# Issue with finding gradle built project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am using some `plugin` `actionbarpulltorefresh`, but in my code `PullToRefreshLayout` is not resolved by the ide. Here's my `build.gradle` file, the problem is that I can't find any source file of this plugin, nothing in the `.gradle` directory

I have some `build.gradle` file this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '18'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : when I put

```
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout; 
private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;
```

I get the message `can not resolve symbol PullToRefreshLayout`. 
 I am using sat version `intelliJ` on which `android studio` is based

Comment: What is the error from the IDE? And which android studio version are you using

Comment: are you using actionbarsherlock along with that? or actionbarcompat?

Comment: @user2511882 no, I should ? if, yes which one ?

Comment: Simply run in console ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

You'll have better luck if you upgrade to new versions of everything:

- Android Studio 0.4.3.
- Android Gradle plugin 0.8. You'll have to edit the `classpath` in your **build.gradle** to:

  ```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
  ```
- Gradle 1.10. You'll have to edit the `distributionUrl` in your **gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties** to:

  ```
  distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-bin.zip
  ```
- Download the 19.0.1 **Android SDK Build Tools** in the **SDK Manager** and instuct the build to use them with this in your **build.gradle**:

  ```
      buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'
  ```

There's a bug that was fixed in Android Studio 0.4.3 that I think is the cause of it not seeing the classes in your **actionbarpulltorefresh** library; the new version of the plugin and Gradle will be necessary for your project to work in 0.4.3. If you upgrade Android Studio it should detect the old versions of the plugin and Gradle and offer to change them for you, but if it doesn't, then you can edit by hand. It won't offer to update the build tools version; you'll have to do that yourself.

Comment: Sorry in fact, it seems very difficult to upgrade because setting `gradle 1.10` throws error of that type : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356015/issue-with-finding-gradle-built-project/21357198?noredirect=1#21357198`, setting `gradle 1.9` throws that I need `gradle 1.6`, which is not supported  by `Android Studio`... So, my question was, where are stored the downloaded files from the `build.gradle` file (` compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'`) ?

Comment: If it's complaining that it needs Gradle 1.6, that's because you haven't updated the Android Gradle version in your build file -- make sure it's set to 0.8 as I indicated in my answer. It's rarely necessary to go digging around in Gradle's cache folders.

Comment: So I downloaded `Android Studio`, I set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'`, I set the `gradle` to `gradle 1.10`, but I get this message `Can't find org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedModuleVersionResult`. What can I do  ?

Comment: That error usually means that there's someplace where the plugin version still isn't set to 0.8. Have you checked all your build.gradle files?

Comment: The only place I think I can find those settings are `jar` files inside my `libs` directory. But how can I find and grep the settings. Btw, is it safe to change settings there ?

Comment: I processed search `zipgrep *string libs/*`, but no matches found