# How to import project - intellij

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am experiencing difficulties to install some project based on a `build.gradle` file. I was told in a precedent post, that I should use `Android Studio` but it seems even more difficult (reported conflict for `gradle 1.10` and `Android Studio`). So I am asking if it is possible to import the project directly in my ide,  `https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh`. If yes, should I put the library folder below in my libs folder ? Here's a screen of the file hierarchy[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Android Studio and Gradle, you could import it as suggested by the [QuickStart page](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/QuickStart-Stock) :

> The easiest way to add ActionBar-PullToRefresh to your project is via
>   Gradle, you just need to add the following dependency to your
>   build.gradle:

```
dependencies {  
    mavenCentral()
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}
```

I believe this is by far the easiest way to include that great library in your project.

If you are using Eclipse, you can still use the library, just download the project and create a create a new library project with the code from "library".

Comment: No I am using `intellij` btw, on either `intellij` or `android studio`, I tried those settings but I didn't manage to make them run successfully : see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356015/issue-with-finding-gradle-built-project

Comment: I had issues importing libraries that way as well. Unfortunately, I cannot give you further advice than what was said in your other thread (updating the tools may work, by updating Android Studio/Gradle and all related gradle.build files, jar should not be a problem as long as you include the correct way), and cleaning/rebuilding the project, then restarting the IDE. If I managed to make it work that way, I'm sure you will as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the guide http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cloning-a-repository-from-github.html
and other github integration http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-github-integration.html